# Pan/scroll image image inside a div container

Tags: css, image, zooming

I have an image inside a container div

```
<div id="container">
   <img id="image" src ....>
</div>
```

and a function that get the image by id and set a zooom using style like this:

```
image.style.transform = `scale(${value})`
```

all works perfectly.

Once image is scaled is getting bigger than the container, how can I set scrolling so I can have the zoom but also can be able to scroll up/down or left/right?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by setting fixed height and width to the container. After that, set `overflow:auto` for the container.

Sample using `div` for demonstration:

```css
.container{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background-color:red;
 overflow:auto;
}
.image{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:yellow;
  transform:scale(10); /*Change scale to 1 to see the original form*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    image
  </div>
</div>
```